# How to get search results in XML format

Tags: iphone, xml, search

I am planning to make an iPhone search app. the user types in the search string. the string will be searched by some search engines like Google, Live, Yahoo ...

I need to get the search result in the XML format. Is there any way to do this. Help needed. Please.

Thanks and regards,
Shibin

Comment: This isn't so much a question on iPhone but more of a API functionality of Google, Live, Yahoo. If you want to display the results on the iPhone easily your best bet is to screen scrape. If you wanted to merge the results, screen scrape and place the details in the SQLite database and then sort them in the db.

Comment: @Rudiger: Can you please say some thing about screen scrape.

Comment: JUst use NSURLConnection to get the webpage and then use the div tags and NSScanner to filter the information out of the div tags. I would recommend using something like googles API at least. If Yahoo doesn't have one and you want to get it you will be forced to screen scrape, and be a slave to their redesigns breaking your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [RESTful search request to Google AJAX](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/#fonje) returns a response in [JSON](http://www.json.org/) format. JSON is a like a very highly stripped-down version of XML.

Google doesn't make its SOAP interface available any longer, so I don't know if you'll be able to get XML from them, at least through a public interface. Luckily for you, JSON responses are trivial to request and to parse on the iPhone.

You can issue the request with [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) and parse the JSON-formatted response on an iPhone with [json-framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/).

For example, to create and submit a search request that is based on the example on the Google AJAX page, you could use ASIHTTPRequest's `-requestWithURL` and `-startSynchronous` methods:

```
NSURL *searchURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=Paris%20Hilton"];
ASIHTTPRequest *googleRequest = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:searchURL];
[googleRequest addRequestHeader:@"Referer" value:[self deviceIPAddress]]; 
[googleRequest startSynchronous];
```

You would build the `NSURL` instance based on your search terms, [escaping](http://simonwoodside.com/weblog/2009/4/22/how_to_really_url_encode/) the request parameters.

If I followed Google's example to the letter, I would also add an API key to this URL. Google asks that you use an API key for REST searches. You should sign up for an API key [over here](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/signup.html) and add it to your requests.

You should also specify the referer IP address in the request header, which in this case would be the local IP address of the iPhone, e.g.:

```
- (NSString *) deviceIPAddress {
    char iphoneIP[255];
    strcpy(iphoneIP,"127.0.0.1"); // if everything fails
    NSHost *myHost = [NSHost currentHost];
    if (myHost) {
        NSString *address = [myHost address];    
        if (address)
            strcpy(iphoneIP, [address cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    }
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",iphoneIP]; 
}
```

There are also asynchronous request methods which are detailed in the ASIHTTPRequest documentation. You would use those to keep the iPhone UI from getting tied up while the search request is made.

In any case, once you have Google's JSON-formatted response in hand, you can use the json-framework `SBJSON` parser object to parse the response into an `NSDictionary` object:

```
NSError *requestError = [googleRequest error];
if (!requestError) {
    SBJSON *jsonParser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
    NSString *googleResponse = [googleRequest responseString];
    NSDictionary *searchResults = [jsonParser objectWithString:googleResponse error:nil];
    [jsonParser release];
    // do stuff with searchResults...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different web service API's available. I would recommend that you use those.

**Google Search API:** http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/ajaxsearch/web.html

Google JS API's often return JSON. But that's easy to work with too. You should easily be able to transform the JSON to XML if needed.

Comment: Thanks,

I a looking for some thing like this "http://www.google.co.in/search?q=football&output=xml" so that i can call it easily from my iPhone code. Google is saying ?output=xml is valid. But it is showing an error. any idea.?

Comment: The error I get is that it is forbidden. Perhaps its a paid service or a service for devices to retrieve results from